# Android store WebView cookies for later use

Tags: android, cookies

I've seen two answers so far, one *works* but is deprecated as of API 21. I am targeting 15>

```
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
CookieSyncManager.getInstance().startSync();
```

Now it's recommended to use:

```
CookieManager.flush()
```

to ensure all cookies are written to disk. But flush() doesn't seem to be a method when I try:

```
mCookieManager.flush();
```

I've made sure to use java.net.cookiemanager, what am I missing?

Comment: Did my answer solve your question? In that case, please accept answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add import android.webkit.CookieManager instead of the java.net.cookiemanager.